# Using geocoder on a child association, how to find all parents in a given location?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

```
class User < AR
  has_many :locations
end

class Location < AR
  belongs_to :user
  geocoded_by :address
end
```

How do I write a query that does this?

```
@users = User._a_query_that_returns_users_in_'Paris'_
```

Answer (score 16):

There might be a more elegant approach, but you can join with the Location table and use the geocoder `near` method to do the query. Something like this:

```
near = Location.near('Paris, France')
@users = User.joins(:locations).merge(near)
```

Comment: In Rails 7, the merge removes all the parent table attributes:


`Profile.joins(:address).merge(Address.near('Dallas, TX')).first.attributes.keys `

  
`Profile Load (3.8ms)  => ["id", "location", "latitude", "longitude", "city", "state", "state_code", "postal_code", "country", "country_code", "created_at", "updated_at", "distance", "bearing"]`